# Excel VBA - Evaluate MIN with two criteria not working

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am currently writing a piece of code, that finds the first date of something for two categories, in the cells.

If one of the cells has a date filled in, it ignores it but if the other cell is blank it runs the evaluate formula.

The problem I am having is the code formula works on the sheet, but not in the code I get Error: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error."

The code is failing on the `xMinScaff = Evaluate("=MIN(IF('Instruction History'!$D:$D=" & cell.address(False, False) & ",IF('Instruction History'!$E:$E=""Scaffold Req"",'Instruction History'!$H:$H)))")` and i would also asumme it will fail on `xMinWorks = Evaluate("=MIN(IF('Instruction History'!$D:$D=" & cell.address(False, False) & ",IF('Instruction History'!$E:$E<>""Scaffold Req"",'Instruction History'!$H:$H)))")` as they are pretty identical.

Here is the code I currently have. Thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim cell, cellRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim xMinScaff, xMinWorks As Double

lastRow = sheets("Current Asset List").cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set cellRange = sheets("Current Asset List").Range("A8:A" & lastRow)

For Each cell In cellRange
    If cell.Offset(0, 24) = "" Then
        xMinScaff = Evaluate("=MIN(IF('Instruction History'!$D:$D=" & cell.address(False, False) & ",IF('Instruction History'!$E:$E=""Scaffold Req"",'Instruction History'!$H:$H)))")
        If xMinScaff <> "0" Then
            cell.offset(0, 24).Value = Format(xMinScaff, "DD/MM/YYYY")
        End If
    End If
    If cell.Offset(0, 25) = "" Then
        xMinWorks = Evaluate("=MIN(IF('Instruction History'!$D:$D=" & cell.address(False, False) & ",IF('Instruction History'!$E:$E<>""Scaffold Req"",'Instruction History'!$H:$H)))")
        If xMinWorks <> "0" Then
            cell.offset(0, 25).Value = Format(xMinWorks, "DD/MM/YYYY")
        End If
    End If
Next cell
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears there are some typos in your code, which could be the cause of your problem, although since you haven't told us where the error is thrown, there could be more issues.  I've corrected the typos below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim cell, cellRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim xMinScaff, xMinWorks As Double

lastRow = sheets("Current Asset List").cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set cellRange = sheets("Current Asset List").Range("A8:A" & lastRow)

For Each cell In cellRange
    If cell.Offset(0, 24) = "" Then
        xMinScaff = Application.Evaluate("=MIN(IF('Instruction History'!$D:$D=" & cell.address(False, False) & ",IF('Instruction History'!$E:$E=""Scaffold Req"",'Instruction History'!$H:$H)))")
        If xMinScaff <> "0" Then
            cell.offset(0, 24).Value = Format(xMinScaff, "DD/MM/YYYY")
        End If
    End If
    If cell.Offset(0, 25) = "" Then
        xMinWorks = Application.Evaluate("=MIN(IF('Instruction History'!$D:$D=" & cell.address(False, False) & ",IF('Instruction History'!$E:$E<>""Scaffold Req"",'Instruction History'!$H:$H)))")
        If xMinWorks <> "0" Then
            cell.offset(0, 25).Value = Format(xMinWorks, "DD/MM/YYYY")
        End If
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: RGA, thanks for picking those up, i have updated the post to define when there code is failing. Thanks!

Comment: @atame its hard to keep track of, but i think you may be missing some conditions in the IF statements in the formula.  what is it you are trying to calculate for `xMinWorks`?  There is likely a much easier way to do it directly in VBA and avoid the formula

Comment: basically its working out the first date soemthing was sent, based on if the ID matches and with 'xMasScaff' if it was scaffold, everyting else comes under 'xMinWorks'. The formula works when i use it on the sheet when pressing CTRL SHIFTENTER. I thought this would be the quickest way of getting it done, as there are several thousand rows to search through. Thanks

Comment: @atame might be a dumb suggestion, but VBA can be annoying like this sometimes.  Try writing it instead as `Application.Evaluate(..)`

Comment: it ran through the loop once and worked fine on the first row, then fail again on the second loop with the same error message. Thanks

Comment: @atame what does the formula look like when typed directly into a cell?  Can you copy that code to a comment here for me?

Comment: Here is what the code looks like in the cell. `{=MIN(IF('Instruction History'!$D:$D=A8,IF('Instruction History'!$E:$E="Scaffold Req",'Instruction History'!$H:$H)))}` & `{=MIN(IF('Instruction History'!$D:$D=A8,IF('Instruction History'!$E:$E<>"Scaffold Req",'Instruction History'!$H:$H)))}`Thanks

Comment: @atame I'm baffled... It looks like the code you've written with the corrections should do exactly that.

Comment: as am I!! I have used a similar evaluate function elsewhere in other codes and works perfectly, although it only had one `if` statement. Is there another way i can do it whilst being quick? Thanks

Comment: @atame is it possible that the IF statements are not passing a valid value to the "Min" function, so it is erroring when not able to evaluate the value?

Comment: @atame Try removing the "=" from the function string, I just editted my answer to include this change